# How to change all elements inside array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I am trying to modify elements inside array. But it says “Cannot assign to value: ‘$0’ is immutable” Is there anyone who knows how to solve it.

My code:

```
boxes.filter({ $0.color == currentColor }).forEach{
    switch newColor {
    case .blue:
        // This assisgnments return error.
        $0 = Blue()
    case .purple:
        $0 = Purple()
    case .red:
        $0 = Red()
    case .yellow:
        $0 = Yellow()
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the elements you get in the forEach ($0) are immutable copies of the elements in the array so not only can't you change them but if you could you would not change the elements in the array but copies of them.

To actually change the content of the array you need to access the element in the array directly by using an index (assuming the elements themselves and their properties are mutable)

```
for index in 0..<boxes.count {
    if boxes[index].color == currentColor {
        switch newColor {
        case .blue:
            boxes[index].color = Blue()
        case .purple:
            boxes[index].color = Purple()
        case .red:
            boxes[index].color= Red()
        case .yellow:
            boxes[index].color = Yellow()
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe the assignments in the switch needs to be changed from

```
boxes[index].color = Blue()
```

to

```
boxes[index] = Blue()
```

and so on, I am not sure what `Blue()` is in this context but the solution still works.

Answer (score 0):

Since one of the answers mentions `map` but doesn't show how to update/overwrite the original `boxes` array I figured I'd add an answer too.

If you want to modify your original array based on the current color you can use `map` like this:

```
boxes = boxes.map { box in 
  guard box.color == currentColor else {
    return box
  }

  switch newColor {
  case .blue: return Blue()
  case .purple: return Purple()
  case .red: return Red()
  case .yellow: return Yellow()
  default: return box // or a different default that suits your needs
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access and modify elements(mutable) by index continue using `enumerated()`:

```
 boxes.enumerated().forEach { (offset, element) in
     guard element.color != currentColor else { return }
     switch newColor {
     case .blue:
         boxes[offset] = Blue()
     case .purple:
         boxes[offset] = Purple()
     case .red:
         boxes[offset] = Red()
     case .yellow:
         boxes[offset] = Yellow()
     }
 }
```